# Puppeteer: set screenshot output dimensions

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

Right now if I take a screenshot of a page in let's say 1920x1080 pixels, that's the image that it outputs.

Woudln't it be possible to resize the image and get exactly the same screenshot but in a smaller size without having to resize the viewport for the screeenshot?

I want a viewport of 1920x1080 but a screenshot of only 400px width.

I was not able to see any options within the screenshot method:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

Comment: Can you use this library to resize screenshot? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Comment: I guess I could, was just wondering if it was possible directly from puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

Even than the question is too old, I ran into the same issue and might be worth to mention the solution that I have used.

You can use `deviceScaleFactor` with smaller values than 1.

The quality of the screenshot might not be as good as using libraries such as [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) but for some purposes might be enough.

So for your case if if you scale down by 0.25 you should get and screenshot 480px wide while still rendering a viewport of 1920px

```
    page.setViewport({
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      deviceScaleFactor: 0.25,
   })
```